# Is NSTS 08209 "Shuttle Systems Design Criteria" available online?

Tags: space-shuttle, history, reference-request

This would be a handy reference, to say the least.  There is a paper copy in at least one [library](http://www.worldcat.org/title/shuttle-systems-design-criteria-vol-1-shuttle-performance-assessment-databook/oclc/671633839) in Houston, so it's not inconceivable that it's online somewhere, but my searches to date have failed.

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer is no. As to why that is, when it is clearly a highly sourced volume of books that isn't that old, I couldn't tell you...

Comment: According to WorldCat, the only associated library that has it is the University of Houston.

Comment: @Phiteros As shown in the link in the question.

Comment: I've requested the book through interlibrary loan....

Comment: @OrganicMarble welp didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A portion of Volume 1 of "NSTS-08209 Shuttle Systems Design Criteria" is available at

https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/shuttle.html

which is a pretty amazing shuttle data dump.

The pdf only contains the highlighted sections.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that a digital copy is stored at the [NASA Technical Standards System](https://standards.nasa.gov/) which requires a NASA account to access.

Otherwise, there does not seem to be a browser-accessible copy at all.

Comment: You know what's really weird about that site you linked to? It says you need an account, but if you click on the "recently published" documents on the right...you can get them.  At least for 5012B, which is the only one I tried.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You can view some but not all of the docs without an account, I believe.

Comment: But you can't search it! :( NASA....

Comment: *sigh* and my interlibrary loan request was rejected for unclear reasons.  I'll have to see if I can travel to the library and check it out.